# Loading Sectors From CD

Tags: assembly, cd, 16-bit, sector

I am new to OS design, and so far have designed one "OS" (Really just a single bootsector), and have decided to try to make a distinct bootloader and "kernel" (still very simple). My question is simple, yet has managed to elude me, through googling, and searching this site (okay, I did find one similar question, but the answer was to vague / advanced for me to be able to use it).

I've looked at int 0x13 AH=02, but that uses tracks, which I don't think CD's use. I saw somewhere that I should use extended read sector (AH=0x42), but I don't see how to use it, because I don't see where I can specify which sector to read, and where the sector should go in RAM.

Here is the question: How do I load sectors from a CD that uses El Torito no emulation. I would appreciate it if you could put the answer in 'simplest form', and try to provide some code, as I am new to this. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I don't know if you need it, but I'm using NASM syntax, so if you could give me the answer in NASM, that would be great.

Comment: Do you have the link to the other question handy?

Comment: Right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856050/how-to-load-kernel-into-memory-from-cd-rom-using-assembly-nasm

Comment: Twenty years is too long ago to remember accurately, but I'm pretty sure there never was a 16-bit BIOS that supported reading cd-rom drives.

Comment: There may not be but I've heard that there is now, I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: You don't *have* to write your own bootloader.  You could make a [Multiboot-compatible](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/html_node/OS-image-format.html#OS-image-format) OS image, so GNU GRUB can load it.  CD boot usually uses syslinux, though, so you could also/instead look into how to make an image that [syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/) can boot.  Then you have an extremely well-tested bootloader that's compatible with huge amounts of hardware, and has an easy text config-file format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, the BIOS puts the drive number you should use for int 13h into the DL register. Then you can use int 13h, ax=4B01h (get emulation status) to determine the disk info, and int 13x function 42h to read 0x800-sized CD sectors with the sector number in the LBA field. Check the [ISOLINUX bootloader](http://git.kernel.org/?p=boot/syslinux/syslinux.git;a=blob;hb=HEAD;f=core/isolinux.asm) for more details. Entrypoint is `_start`, routine to read sectors is `getlinsec_cdrom`.

Edit: read [the documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D42h%3a_Extended_Read_Sectors_From_Drive) on int 13h extensions about how to use it. Basically, you need to pass a filled structure, with the sector number, count, and address of the buffer where to put the read data.

Comment: Two questions, how do I tell the CPU where to put the sector, do I use ES:BX, or something else? Also, does this work in 16-bit Real Mode?

Comment: Also, how do I tell the computer which sector to read? Is it still Cl?

Answer (score 0):

My boot loader think it is loaded at 0x07c0:0x000 rather than 0x0000:0x7c00. But it works. I'm using GNU tools.

This is the assembly:

```
/**
 * This is the first stage bootloader. It is used to loader the second
 * stage bootloader.
 */



# The address of this bootloader been loaded by BIOS
.equ BOOTLOADER_ADDR, 0x07c0

# The signature for bootloader.
.equ BOOT_MACHINE_SIGNATURE, 0xaa55

# The offset of the start of BPB (BIOS Parameter Block).
.equ BOOT_MACHINE_BPB_START, 0x03

# The offset of the end of BPB (BIOS Parameter Block).
.equ BOOT_MACHINE_BPB_END, 0x5a

# The offset of the end of the partition table.
.equ BOOT_MACHINE_PART_END, 0x1fe

/* The segment of disk buffer. The disk buffer MUST be 32K long and
   cannot straddle a 64K boundary.  */
.equ BOOT_MACHINE_BUFFER_SEG, 0x7000

.macro PRINT str
        pusha
        movw $\str, %si
        call print
        popa
.endm

.macro DUMP begin, size
        movw $\begin, %si
        movw $\size, %cx
        call dump
.endm

.macro RESET_DISK drive
        pusha
        movb $\drive, %dl
        movw 0x0, %ah
        call reset_disk
        popa
.endm

.macro READ_SECTORS drive, head, cylinder, sector, count, destination
        pusha
        movw $\destination, %ax
        movw %ax, %es
        xorw %bx, %bx
        movb $\drive, %dl
        movb $\head, %dh
        movb $\cylinder, %ch
        movb $\sector, %cl
        movb $\count, %al
        call read_sectors
        popa
.endm

/**
 * Entry point
 */
        .file "boot.S"
        .text
        .code16
        .org 0x0000
.globl _start, start;
_start:
start:
# The offset 0x0000 must be a jump to the reset of code.
        jmp after_BPB
        nop
        . = _start + BOOT_MACHINE_BPB_START
        . = _start + 4
disk_addr_packet:
        .byte 0x10              # (00h) size of packet
        .byte 0x00              # (01h) reserved
        .word 0x0001            # (02h) number of blocks to transfer
        .word 0x8000, 0x0000    # (04h) DWORD, transfer buffer
        .word 0x0010, 0x0000    # (08h) QWORD, starting absolute block number
        .word 0x0000, 0x0000
                                # (10h)
        . = _start + BOOT_MACHINE_BPB_END
after_BPB:
        cli                             # disable interrupt.
        movw $BOOTLOADER_ADDR, %ax      # set address expression
        movw %ax, %ds
        movw %ax, %es
        # movw $BOOTLOADER_ADDR, %sp    # stack grows down to 0x0000
        PRINT message_booting

# We need make sure the BIOS supports the INT 13 extensions.
int13_ext_check:
        mov $0x41, %ah
        mov $0x55aa, %bx
        # DL should contain the drive value. But we'd better save it.
        push %dx
        int $0x13
        jc int13_ext_check_failed
        cmpw $0xaa55, %bx
        jne int13_ext_check_failed
        andw $0x001, %cx        # if function 42h-44h,47h,48h are supported
        jz int13_ext_check_failed
        jmp read_cd_content

int13_ext_check_failed:
        PRINT message_no_int13_ext
        jmp loop

read_cd_content:

        # CHS mode : Cylinder-Head-Sector mode.
        # LBA mode : Logical Block Addressing mode.
        # When we use INT 13 extension, we use LBA mode in which
        # the device is taken as a single large device.

        PRINT message_loading_img
        pop %dx
        movw $disk_addr_packet, %si
        movb $0x42, %ah
        int $0x13
        jc error_read_sectors

        DUMP 0x0400, 16
        jmp loop

error_read_sectors:
        PRINT message_sector_read_err
        jmp loop
loop:
        PRINT message_halt
        cli
        hlt
        jmp loop
message_booting:
        .asciz "Booting ...\r\n"
message_halt:
        .asciz "Boot Halt.\r\n"
message_no_int13_ext:
        .asciz "No INT13 extension. Boot failed.\r\n"
message_loading_img:
        .asciz "Loading OS image.\r\n"
message_sector_read_err:
        .asciz "Sector read error.\r\n"
hexdump:
        .byte 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08

/**
 * Write the string pointed to by %si
 * Each char is wrote by using BIOS INT 0x10.
 * BIOS INT 0x10:
 * AH = 0x0e
 * AL = Character to write.
 * BH = Page Number (Should be 0)
 * BL = Foreground color (Graphics Modes Only)
 * When using the function, put the string address to SI. The string
 * should end with 0.
 */
1:
        movw $0x0001, %bx
        movb $0xe, %ah
        int $0x10
print:
        lodsb   # Loads a byte pointed by SI into AL.
        cmpb $0, %al
        jne 1b
        ret

/**
 * Print the register's value.
 *
print_reg:

/**
 * Dump a area of data.
 * Display 8 bytes of code each line. For every 10 line will wait for any key to continue.
 * SI = The start address
 * CX = The size of area to dump
 */
index:
.byte '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
.byte 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
enter_key:
.asciz "\r\n"
1:
        ret
dump:
        movb $10, %dl           # DL = row counter, DH = column counter.
        movb $8, %dh
        cld
2:
        cmpw $0, %cx
        je 1b
        xorw %ax, %ax           # clean the AX at first.
        lodsb                   # loads the byte pointed by SI into AL.
        push %ax                # because AH will be used, so we save AX.
        shr $4, %ax             # show first 4 bits.
        movw $index, %di
        addw %ax, %di
        movb (%di), %al
        movb $0xe, %ah
        movw $0x0001, %bx       # Page number = 0, froeground color = 1.
        int $0x10
        pop %ax
        andw $0x000f, %ax       # show last 4 bits.
        movw $index, %di
        addw %ax, %di
        movb (%di), %al
        movb $0xe, %ah
        movw $0x0001, %bx
        int $0x10
        movb $' ', %al          # display a space
        movb $0xe, %ah
        movw $0x0001, %bx
        int $0x10
        dec %cx
        dec %dh
        jnz 2b
        PRINT enter_key
        movb $8,%dh
        jmp 2b

/**
 * Reset the disk controller, let it go to the first sector.
 * BIOS INT 0x13
 * AH = 0x00
 * DL = Drive to reset.
 * Return:
 * AH = Status code.
 * CF = Clear if success, set if failure.
 */
reset_disk:
        int $0x13
        jc reset_disk
        ret

/**
 * Read sectors into memory
 * BIOS INT 0x13
 * AH = 0x02
 * AL = Numbers of sectors to read.
 * CH = Low eight bits of cylinder number.
 * CL = Sector Number Bits 0-5. Bits 6-7 are for hard disks only.
 * DH = Head number.
 * DL = Drive number (Bit 7 set for hard disk)
 * ES:BX = Buffer to read sector to
 * Return
 * AH = Status code
 * AL = Number of sectors read
 * CF = Set if failure, cleaned if successful.
 */
read_sectors:
        int $0x13
        jc read_sectors
        ret

        .fill 0x1fe - (. - _start) ,1,0
        .org _start + BOOT_MACHINE_PART_END
        .word BOOT_MACHINE_SIGNATURE
```

This is the Makefile:

```
all:
        i686-elf-as -o boot.o boot.S
        i686-elf-ld --oformat=binary -Ttext=0x0 -o boot.bin boot.o

# Make fd is for test only, our target media is CD.
fd: all
        dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=floppy.flp
        qemu-system-i386 -fda floppy.flp

cd: all
        mkdir -p iso/boot
        cp boot.bin iso/boot/loader.sys
        mkisofs -R -J -c boot/bootcat \
                -b boot/loader.sys -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 \
                -input-charset utf-8 \
                -o ./boot.iso ./iso
        qemu-system-i386 -cdrom boot.iso

clean:
        @rm -rf iso boot.o boot.bin floppy.flp boot.iso
```

**The key is to understanding how Seg:Offset represents address in real mode.**

Comment: A lot of BIOSes use 0x0000:0x7c00 as the location to jump to. Such a jump sets CS=0x0000 and IP=0x7c00 . Some BIOSes (including the one in QEMU) jump to 0x07c0:0x0000 so CS=0x07c0 and IP=0x0000 .

Comment: 0x07c0:0x0000 = (0x07c0<<4)+0 = 0x07c00 physical address. 0x0000:0x7c00 = (0x0000<<4)+7c00 = 0x07c00 physical address. Both map to the same location. The BIOS can jump to any segment:offset that maps to 0x07c00. (so you can't rely on _CS_ being a particular value) Bootloader code shouldn't rely on values in _CS_ (and of course _DS_, _ES_). You just need to set them to what your code needs. The segment you use is dependent on the origin/offset (-Ttext determines that). -Ttext=0 requires a _DS_ being set to 0x07c0 . -Ttext=0x7c00 requires _DS_ being 0. Doesn't matter which you use.

Comment: If you ever write bootloader code that needs near absolute indirect jumps (your code doesn't, just pointing it out) then CS actually needs to be set up properly. That is usually done by doing a far jump to a label in your code. In the code *_after_BPB* you could add `jmp  $BOOTLOADER_ADDR, $.mainjmp` followed by the label `.mainjmp:` . This literally would far jump to the next instruction.The side effect now is that _CS_ will be BOOTLOADER_ADDR (0x07c0) .A I said,doesn't apply to the code you have written.Only pointing it out for anyone that might be curious how to set CS to a particular value